# Running old Linux distros with VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'd like to run a pretty old Linux distribution (say from 2003) on VirtualBox. It doesn't look easy to find any ISO and package sources. Has any one try this rather strange adventure?

Thanks,

Comment: VirtualBox is perfectly capable of running older distros. Are you actually asking where to FIND downloads of older distros?

Comment: It's really dependant on what distro you want to run. Quite a lot of distro's (such as Linux Mint) have the older versions listed for downloading on their websites.

Comment: `...to run a pretty old Linux distribution (say from 2007)...` That's not old! Not even close! I mean, not only from a "that box sits there since 20 years, it works" view of things, but also from "we have that production server, still supported, still under maintenance" view.

Comment: actually 2007 is a typo. i need one from 2003.

Comment: Just download the distro ISO....As written this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the distro you want, have a google around their websites. As Oliver said, many of them keep older versions for you to download.

For example, I just checked that I can get early Ubuntu ISO's (certainly back as far as 2006) and Slackware. Took me about 6 seconds of googling.

It is relatively common to keep a wide range of ISO's for historical and research reasons.